# What is a LaTeX editor that syncs automatically?

Tags: editors, overleaf, forward-inverse-search, dropbox

Basically something I could use to work on Overleaf docs when lost internet connectivity or Chrome is not responding.

Oh and runs on windows.

Pdf-code sync would be nice too.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment I'm using the git integration from overleaf, pull the content and then I edit the content locally with Visual Studio Code and the Latex-Workshop-Extension.

For me, this workflow is quite nice.

Comment: Can you do this from dropbox I'm not familiar with github or how to use it.  Basically I'm most concerned about undoing a bunch of work when saving

Comment: It is possible to use Dropbox but then you need to have a paid plan. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/user/subscription/plans)

Comment: actually doesn't git also require a paid plan?

Comment: Integration with github needs a paid plan. But if you go to the settings of a project and then go to git, you can clone it as a git repository. I think this should be free because I do not have a paid plan and I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

TeXshop with Flashmode will update your pdf as you write in LaTeX the editor window.

Comment: Does it allow you to find your place in the code for large documents and does it sync the code automatically?

Comment: If you command-click on a place in the pdf window, the cursor will move to the corresponding location in the tex window (and vice versa). And Flashmode syncs the code automatically, checking for changes in the source every fraction of a second. (Note, TeXshop runs under MacOS.)

Answer (score 0):

TeXworks also.

Once compiled, if you right-click on a PDF page in the viewer of TeXworks, it will show the option to go to source code,  jumping to the editor windows.  In the same way, the right-clik on the source code show a menu with the option of jump to that part on the PDF.   In this case you must press the compilation button every time yo want to synchronize both windows, but with large-complex documents the live preview is  always a bad idea.

For automatic compilation but without synchronization, you can use Gummi. This could be more convenient to test some code in small documents (some complex tables, a diagram, etc.)  but in large documents  this can produce  significant delays and is better deactivate this feature.

Comment: does it sync the code automatically?

Comment: @HaoS  Not sure what mean  "automatic" for you.  Without doubt removing the `$synctexoption`  in the menu Edit→Preferences, you will have no  synchronization automatically . `:-)` As said, the compilation is not automatic, you have the hard work of push a green button if you want to see the PDF updated, but the compilation includes the synchronization without making anything additional. Then, in this sense the synchronization is "automatic" ....

Comment: I mean just sync via dropbox if  I edit the file via overleaf or someone else edits the file